# Rust GTK+ example doesn't compile because Option<&str>: From<Option<&String>> is not satisfied

Tags: rust, gtk

In the [Rust GTK examples](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples), there's one called [notebook](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples/blob/master/src/bin/notebook.rs). It doesn't compile:

```
for i in 1..4 {
    let title = format!("sheet {}", i);
    let label = gtk::Label::new(Some(&title));
    //let label = gtk::Label::new(Some("test1111")); # works well
    notebook.create_tab(&title, label.upcast());
}
```

The error is:

```
the trait bound `std::option::Option<&str>: std::convert::From<std::option::Option<&std::string::String>>` is not satisfied
```

What is it about and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you're working with an old copy of `gtk-rs/examples`. In the [current master](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples/blob/bf3a47f47c6fb946854718054b1d41186e6bb0fc/src/bin/notebook.rs), the loop in `notebook.rs` looks like this:

```
let mut notebook = Notebook::new();

for i in 1..4 {
    let title = format!("sheet {}", i);
    let label = gtk::Label::new(&*title);
    notebook.create_tab(&title, label.upcast());
}
```

This code compiles - the difference is that it uses `&*title` to convert a `String` into something convertible to `Option<&str>`.

In [PR#447](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk/pull/447), `gtk-rs` switched from using `Option<&str>` to `Into<Option<&str>>` in parameters of functions that accept an optional string, including `gtk::Label::new`. This made the API more ergonomic, because a constant string argument can be written as `"string"` instead of `Some("string")`. However, the change is not 100% backward-compatible - the `Into<Option<...>>` pattern doesn't support passing `Some(&string)` with `string` being an owned `String` - one must write `&*string` or the more explicit `string.as_str()` instead.